# Issue java.lang.Exception: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, locking

When I try to run a code I have this mistake: java.lang.Exception: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction. I have see the inoodb status and I get this. How can I translate this into a language which I know?. How can I modify the time for the innodb variable?.

Thanks

```
mysql> show engine innodb status\g

| InnoDB |      |
=====================================
130117 13:25:22 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 19 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 5, signal count 5
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 40, OS waits 2
RW-shared spins 6, OS waits 3; RW-excl spins 0, OS waits 0
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 46088
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 45663 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 5
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, process no 20582, OS thread id 139811275994880
MySQL thread id 39, query id 169 localhost root
show engine innodb status
---TRANSACTION 0 46087, ACTIVE 8 sec, process no 20582, OS thread id 139811275593472 inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 44, query id 168 172.17.150.33 root update
INSERT INTO albaranes    (id_cuenta_emisora,id_cuenta_receptora,id_pedido,id_formato_documento,descuento,nombre_report,destino_report) VALUES (    19 ,                           23 ,                         1 ,                                   2 ,                        0.0,                                null,null   )
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 8 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 228 n bits 256 index `PRIMARY` of table `cluw`.`pedidos` trx id  0 46087 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 106 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 13; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;; 1: len 6; hex 00000000b403; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex    800000002d0110; asc     -  ;; 3: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;; 4: len 4; hex 00000017; asc     ;;   5: len 10; hex 32303132303430303031; asc 2012040001;; 6: len 8; hex 8000124ca5887d00; asc    L  } ;; 7: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 8: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;; 9: SQL NULL; 10: SQL NULL; 11: SQL NULL; 12: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 46083, ACTIVE 9 sec, process no 20582, OS thread id 139811275794176
11 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 9 row lock(s), undo log entries 7
MySQL thread id 43, query id 157 172.17.150.33 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 46084, sees < 0 46084
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0, aio writes: 0,
ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
73 OS file reads, 9 OS file writes, 9 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.11 writes/s, 0.11 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2,
0 inserts, 0 merged recs, 0 merges
Hash table size 17393, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 2.53 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 0 10153404
Log flushed up to   0 10153404
Last checkpoint at  0 10151824
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
12 log i/o's done, 0.11 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 20742848; in additional pool allocated 1048576
Dictionary memory allocated 188160
Buffer pool size   512
Free buffers       424
Database pages     87
Modified db pages  14
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages read 87, created 0, written 1
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
2 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 20582, id 139811124684544, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 7, updated 0, deleted 0, read 70
0.37 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 2.89 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And this is the code which give me problems:

```
public TDatosRetorno sincronizarPedidos(Tdatospedidos pedido,int metodo_facturacion,int proveedor){
        TDatosRetorno resultado = new TDatosRetorno();


        System.out.println("Voy a sincronizar los pedidos ahora mismo");
        //System.out.println("Pedidos"+pedidos);
        System.out.println(pedido.getId_cuenta()+" y pedido es:"+pedido.getId_pedido());
        try {
        this.conexion = conectar();
        this.conexion.setAutoCommit(false);

        int estado_pedido=0;
        Date f_aprobacion=null;
        boolean pedido_provisionado = true;

        Date f_provision=null;
        String unidad_duracion_contrato=" ";
        int duracion_contrato=0;
        Date f_inicio_contrato = new Date();
        Date f_fin_contrato = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        //int id_cuenta=buscar_cuentaPedidos_ccis(pedido.getId_cuenta(),proveedor);
        //System.out.println("id_cuenta es:"+id_cuenta);
        SQL="INSERT pedidos (id_pedido,id_estado_pedido,id_cuenta,n_pedido,f_creacion,es_actualizacion,id_pedido_actualizado,f_inicio_contrato,f_fin_contrato,f_aprobacion,estado_envio)"+
        " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        System.out.println("LA SQL de insertar pedidos es:"+SQL);
        //int key=0;
        this.pstm = this.conexion.prepareStatement(SQL,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        this.pstm.setInt(1, pedido.getId_pedido());
        this.pstm.setInt(2, 1);
        this.pstm.setInt(3, pedido.getId_cuenta());
        this.pstm.setString(4, pedido.getN_pedido());
        Object objPed = pedido.getF_creacion();
        if(objPed!=null){
            System.out.println("Fecha de creación es diferente de nulo");
            java.sql.Date f_creacionAux = new java.sql.Date(pedido.getF_creacion().getTime());  
            this.pstm.setDate(5, f_creacionAux);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Fecha de creación es nulo");
            this.pstm.setDate(5, null);
        }

        this.pstm.setBoolean(6, pedido.isEs_actualizacion());
        this.pstm.setInt(7, pedido.getId_pedido_actualizado());
        this.pstm.setDate(8, null);
        this.pstm.setDate(9, null);
        this.pstm.setDate(10, null);

        this.pstm.setInt(11, 0);




        System.out.println("Vamos a hacer la insercción de pedidos");
         int ejecutado =  this.pstm.executeUpdate();
            if(ejecutado==0){   
               System.out.println("Ejecutado tiene valor 0");
                throw new Exception("Error al grabar Pedidos");

         }

        ResultSet rs = this.pstm.getGeneratedKeys(); 
        int key = 0;
        if (rs != null && rs.next()) { 
            key = rs.getInt(1);

        }   
         System.out.println("El pedido tiene una key de:"+key);     
        System.out.println("Estamos fuera de pedidos ya");
        if(pedido.getDatos_SV()!=null){



            for (int i=0;i<pedido.getDatos_SV().length;i++){
                servID=new int[pedido.getDatos_SV().length];
                SQL="INSERT INTO servidores_virtuales (id_servidor_virtual,id_pedido,nombre_servidor,duracion_contrato,cpu_cant,ram_cant,hdd_cant,hdd_unidad,sv_pvp,cpu_pvp,ram_pvp,hdd_pvp,sv_pvp_dist,cpu_pvp_dist,ram_pvp_dist,hdd_pvp_dist,ip_pvp,ip_pvp_dist,ip_polled_pvp,ip_polled_pvp_dist,ip_custom_pvp,ip_custom_pvp_dist,data_center,cluster,plantilla,estado_aprobacion,f_aprobacion,f_provision,es_actualizacion,f_actualizacion,disco_almacenamiento) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
                System.out.println("LA SQL A METER ES:"+SQL);
                System.out.println("El número de servidores a meter es:"+pedido.getDatos_SV().length);


                PreparedStatement pstmSv = this.conexion.prepareStatement(SQL,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                //System.out.println("El virtual server id que voy a meter tiene id de ccis:"+pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getId_servidor_virtual_ccis());

                pstmSv.setInt(1, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getId_servidor_virtual());
                pstmSv.setInt(2, pedido.getId_pedido()); //Last insert id de pedido

                System.out.println("Nombre del servidor:"+pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getNombre_servidor());
                pstmSv.setString(3, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getNombre_servidor());
                pstmSv.setString(4, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDuracion_contrato());
                pstmSv.setInt(5, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getCpu_cant());
                pstmSv.setString(6, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getRam_cant());
                pstmSv.setString(7, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getHdd_cant());
                pstmSv.setString(8, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getHdd_unidad());
                pstmSv.setDouble(9, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getSv_pvp());
                pstmSv.setDouble(10, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getCpu_pvp());
                pstmSv.setDouble(11, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getRam_pvp());
                pstmSv.setDouble(12, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getHdd_pvp());
                pstmSv.setDouble(13, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getSv_pvp_dist());
                pstmSv.setDouble(14, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getCpu_pvp_dist());
                pstmSv.setDouble(15, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getRam_pvp_dist());
                pstmSv.setDouble(16, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getHdd_pvp_dist());
                pstmSv.setDouble(17, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getIp_pvp());
                pstmSv.setDouble(18, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getIp_pvp_dist());
                pstmSv.setDouble(19, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getIp_polled_pvp());
                pstmSv.setDouble(20, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getIp_polled_pvp_dist());
                pstmSv.setDouble(21, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getIp_custom_pvp());
                pstmSv.setDouble(22, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getIp_custom_pvp_dist());
                pstmSv.setString(23, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getData_center());
                pstmSv.setString(24, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getCluster());
                pstmSv.setString(25, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getPlantilla());
                pstmSv.setInt(26, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getEstado_aprobacion());
                //Chequear nulos
                Object objAprob = pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_aprobacion();
                if(objAprob!=null){


                    java.sql.Date f_aprobacionAux = new java.sql.Date(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_aprobacion().getTime());  
                    pstmSv.setDate(27, f_aprobacionAux);

                }else{
                    System.out.println("Nuloooooooooooooooooo");
                    pstmSv.setDate(27, null);
                }
                Object obj=pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_provision();
                if(obj==null){
                        System.out.println("Nulooooooooooooooo");
                        pstmSv.setDate(28, null);
                }else{
                  java.sql.Date f_provisionAux = new java.sql.Date(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_provision().getTime());
                  pstmSv.setDate(28, f_provisionAux);
                }  


                pstmSv.setBoolean(29, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].isEs_actualizacion());
                if(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_actualizacion()!=null){
                    java.sql.Date f_actualizacionAux =new java.sql.Date(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_actualizacion().getTime());
                    pstmSv.setDate(30, f_actualizacionAux);     
                }else{

                    pstmSv.setDate(30, null);

                }
                pstmSv.setString(31, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDisco_almacenamiento());





                System.out.println("El estado de aprobación del pedido es:"+pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getEstado_aprobacion());                    
                switch(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getEstado_aprobacion()){


                     case 0:{
                         switch(estado_pedido){
                             case 0:{
                                 estado_pedido =1;
                                 break;
                             }
                             case 1:{
                                 estado_pedido =1;
                                 break;
                             }
                             case 2:{
                                 estado_pedido = 1;
                                 break;
                             }

                         }
                         break;
                     }
                     case 1:{
                         switch(estado_pedido){

                            case 0:{
                                estado_pedido = 2;
                                break;
                            }
                            case 1:{
                                estado_pedido =1;
                                break;
                            }
                            case 2:{
                                estado_pedido=2;
                                break;
                            }
                         }
                         break;
                     }

                }

                if(estado_pedido==2){
                    if(f_aprobacion==null){
                        f_aprobacion = pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_aprobacion();
                    }else{
                        if (f_aprobacion.compareTo(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_aprobacion())<0){

                            f_aprobacion = pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_aprobacion();
                        }

                    }

                    if(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_provision()==null){
                        pedido_provisionado = false;
                    }
                    if(f_provision == null){
                        pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_provision();
                    }else{
                        if(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_provision().compareTo(f_provision)>0){
                            f_provision=pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getF_provision();
                        }
                    }

                }

                String [] duracion = pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDuracion_contrato().split("");
                int cant=0;
                if(duracion[0].trim().isEmpty()){
                    cant=0;
                }else{
                    cant = Integer.parseInt(duracion[0].trim());
                }

                String unidad = duracion[1].trim().toUpperCase();


                if(unidad_duracion_contrato ==" "){
                    System.out.println("unidad_duracion_contrato es vacio y se llena");
                    unidad_duracion_contrato = unidad;
                    duracion_contrato = cant;
                    System.out.println("La duración de contrato es:"+cant);
                    System.out.println("La unidad de duracion de contrato es:"+unidad_duracion_contrato);
                }/*else{*/
                    /* if(unidad_duracion_contrato != unidad){
                         System.out.println("Esto es lo que me falla donde unidad_duracion_contrato es:"+unidad_duracion_contrato +" y unidad es:"+unidad);
                     }
                    if (unidad_duracion_contrato != unidad || duracion_contrato != cant){
                        throw new Exception ("Pedido con diferentes duraciones de contrato: "+key);
                    }*/
                /*}*/
                System.out.println("Voy a hacer el insert de los servidores virtuales");    


                int ejecutadoServiVirtual =  pstmSv.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("ejecutadoServiVirtual es:"+ejecutadoServiVirtual);
                if(ejecutadoServiVirtual==0){                         
                    throw new Exception("Error al grabar Pedidos");

             }
                ResultSet rsServ = pstmSv.getGeneratedKeys(); 

                if (rsServ != null && rsServ.next()) { 
                  int  keyServidorV = rsServ.getInt(1);
                  System.out.println("El keyServidorV es:"+keyServidorV);
                } 



                /*for(int h=0;h< pedido.getDatos_SV().length;h++){

                    System.out.println("h---------->"+h);*/
                    switch (metodo_facturacion){
                        case 1: //DIODE
                        case 2: //DIRECTO 
                        {
                              TDatosRetorno result_coste = insertar_PrecioCoste_SV(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getId_servidor_virtual(),pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getPlantilla(),pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDisco_almacenamiento(),proveedor);

                              if(result_coste.getError()==-1){
                                  throw new Exception(result_coste.getDescripcion_error());

                              }
                              break;
                        }
                    }
                /*}*/


                int ind =0;

                /*for(int z =0;z<pedido.getDatos_SV().length;z++){  */ //Meter sa dentro de servidores virtuales

                    if(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()!=null){  

                        SQL="INSERT INTO servicios_adicionales (id_servicio_adicional,id_servidor_virtual,sku,descripcion,cantidad,unidad,pvp,unidad_dist,pvp_dist,base_pvp,base_pvp_dist) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                           PreparedStatement pstmSA = this.conexion.prepareStatement(SQL,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                           for(int k=0;k<pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales().length;k++){
                                servID[i]=pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getId_servidor_virtual();
                                System.out.println("k------------>"+k);

                                pstmSA.setInt(1, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getId_servicios_adicionales());
                                pstmSA.setInt(2, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getId_servidor_virtual());  //Nuestro lastinsert
                                System.out.println("SKU----->"+pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getSku());
                                pstmSA.setString(3, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getSku());
                                System.out.println("Descripción---->"+pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getDescripcion());
                                pstmSA.setString(4, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getDescripcion());
                                pstmSA.setInt(5, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getCantidad());
                                pstmSA.setString(6, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getUnidad());
                                pstmSA.setDouble(7, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getPvp());
                                pstmSA.setString(8, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getUnidad_dist());
                                pstmSA.setDouble(9, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getPvp_dist());
                                pstmSA.setDouble(10, pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getBase_pvp());
                                pstmSA.setDouble(11,pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getBase_pvp_dist());

                                ind++;

                               System.out.println("Voy a ejecutandoSA ");
                                int ejecutadoSA =  pstmSA.executeUpdate();
                                if(ejecutadoSA==0){ 
                                   throw new Exception("Error al grabar envíos Servicios Adicionales");
                                }


                                ResultSet rsSA = pstmSA.getGeneratedKeys(); 
                                int  keyServidorA=0;
                                if (rsSA != null && rsSA.next()) { 
                                    keyServidorA = rsSA.getInt(1); 

                                }



                                /*for(int k=0;k<pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales().length;k++){*/

                                       switch(metodo_facturacion){
                                          case 1:// DIODE
                                          case 2: //DIRECTA 
                                          {

                                              //System.out.println("keyServidorA es:"+keyServidorA);
                                              System.out.println("Sku es------------->"+pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getSku());
                                              TDatosRetorno result_coste = insertar_precioCoste_SA(pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getId_servicios_adicionales(),pedido.getDatos_SV()[i].getDatos_servicios_adicionales()[k].getSku(),1);

                                              if(result_coste.getError() == -1){
                                                  throw new Exception (result_coste.getDescripcion_error());
                                              }
                                              break;
                                          }
                                       }
                                   /*}*/





                           }



                    }
                /*}*/
                System.out.println("He acabado de grabar servicios adicionales");





         }







        }else{
            throw new Exception("Pedido sin servidores virtuales:"+pedido.getId_pedido());  
        }
        System.out.println("El método de facturación es:"+metodo_facturacion);
        switch(metodo_facturacion){

            case 1:{
                System.out.println("Estado_Pedido es_"+estado_pedido);
                if(estado_pedido == 1 || estado_pedido == 2){

                    if(pedido.isEs_actualizacion()){
                        f_inicio_contrato = pedido.getF_creacion();
                        f_fin_contrato = obtener_fecha_fin_contrato(pedido.getId_pedido_actualizado());
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("f_aprobacion es:"+f_aprobacion);
                        if(f_aprobacion == null)
                            f_inicio_contrato = pedido.getF_creacion();
                        else
                            f_inicio_contrato = f_aprobacion;
                        System.out.println("Unidad_duracion_contrato es:"+unidad_duracion_contrato);
                        switch(unidad_duracion_contrato){

                        case "DAY":{
                               Calendar calDays = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                               calDays.setTime(f_inicio_contrato); 
                               calDays.add(Calendar.DATE, duracion_contrato);   
                               f_fin_contrato = calDays.getTime();
                               break;
                           }
                           case "WEEK":{

                               Calendar calDays = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                               calDays.setTime(f_inicio_contrato); 
                               calDays.add(Calendar.DATE, duracion_contrato*7);     
                               f_fin_contrato = calDays.getTime();
                               break;
                           }
                           case "MONTH":{
                               System.out.println("Estoy en mes y la duracion de contrato es:"+duracion_contrato);
                               Calendar calDays = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                               calDays.setTime(f_inicio_contrato); 
                               calDays.add(Calendar.MONTH, duracion_contrato);  
                                f_fin_contrato = calDays.getTime();
                                System.out.println("El fin de contrato es:"+f_fin_contrato);
                               break;
                           }
                           case "YEAR":{
                              Calendar calDays = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                              calDays.setTime(f_inicio_contrato); 
                              calDays.add(Calendar.YEAR, duracion_contrato); 
                              f_fin_contrato = calDays.getTime();
                              break;
                           }
                        }
                    }

                    if(pedido_provisionado){
                        estado_pedido = 3;
                    }
                }
                break;
            } 
            case 2:{
                if(estado_pedido == 2){

                    if(pedido.isEs_actualizacion()){
                        f_inicio_contrato = pedido.getF_creacion();
                        f_inicio_contrato = obtener_fecha_fin_contrato(pedido.getId_pedido_actualizado());
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("f_aprobacion es:"+f_aprobacion);
                        if(f_aprobacion == null){
                            System.out.println("f_aprobacion es nulo entonces hay"+pedido.getF_creacion());
                            f_inicio_contrato = pedido.getF_creacion();
                        }   
                        else
                            f_inicio_contrato = f_aprobacion;

                        switch (unidad_duracion_contrato){
                           case "DAY":{
                               Calendar calDays = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                               calDays.setTime(f_inicio_contrato); 
                                calDays.add(Calendar.DATE, duracion_contrato);  
                               f_fin_contrato = calDays.getTime();
                               break;
                           }
                           case "WEEK":{

                               Calendar calDays = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                               calDays.setTime(f_inicio_contrato); 
                               calDays.add(Calendar.DATE, duracion_contrato*7);     
                               f_fin_contrato = calDays.getTime();
                               break;
                           }
                           case "MONTH":{

                               Calendar calDays = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                               calDays.setTime(f_inicio_contrato); 
                               calDays.add(Calendar.MONTH, duracion_contrato);  
                                f_fin_contrato = calDays.getTime();
                               break;
                           }
                           case "YEAR":{
                              Calendar calDays = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                              calDays.setTime(f_inicio_contrato); 
                              calDays.add(Calendar.YEAR, duracion_contrato); 
                              f_fin_contrato = calDays.getTime();
                              break;
                           }
                        }

                        if(pedido_provisionado){
                            estado_pedido = 3;
                        }
                    }

                }
                break;
              }
            } 






            int id_formato_documento;
            System.out.println("Voy a mandar un albarán a:"+pedido.getId_cuenta());
            Tcuenta cuenta_receptora = buscar_Cuenta(pedido.getId_cuenta());  
            if(cuenta_receptora.getCuenta()!= -1){  //AquÃ­ habÃ­a -1
                System.out.println("Cuenta receptora la cuenta padre es:"+cuenta_receptora.getCuenta_padre());
                Tcuenta cuenta_emisora = buscar_cuenta_emisora(cuenta_receptora.getCuenta_padre());
                while(cuenta_emisora.getCuenta()!=-1){  //AquÃ­ habÃ­a -1

                    if(cuenta_emisora.getNivel()==0){
                        id_formato_documento = 1;
                    }else{
                        id_formato_documento = 2;
                    }

                    TDatosRetorno result1 = grabarAlbaran(pedido.getId_pedido(),cuenta_emisora.getCuenta(),cuenta_receptora.getCuenta(),cuenta_receptora.getDescuento(),id_formato_documento);
                    if(result1.getError()==-1){                  //Nuestro
                        throw new Exception(result1.getDescripcion_error());
                    }
                    cuenta_receptora = cuenta_emisora;

                    cuenta_emisora = buscar_cuenta_emisora(cuenta_receptora.getCuenta_padre()); //Tipo String n_cuenta_padre
                    System.out.println("Cuenta receptora es:"+cuenta_receptora.getCuenta());
                }
            }else{
                throw new Exception("La cuenta del pedido: "+pedido.getId_cuenta()+"no existe");
            }

                TDatosRetorno result;
            for(int x=0;x<servID.length;x++){
                System.out.println(servID[x]);
                if(servID[x]!=0){
                    result = generar_lineas_albaran(pedido,pedido.getId_pedido(),metodo_facturacion,servID[x]);
                    if(result.getError()==-1){
                        throw new Exception(result.getDescripcion_error());
                    }
                }
            } 


                System.out.println("Voy a hacer el update de los pedidos");
                SQL = "UPDATE pedidos SET ";

                if(f_aprobacion != null){

                    SQL=SQL+" f_aprobacion = ?,";
                }

                if((metodo_facturacion == 1)||(metodo_facturacion == 2 && (estado_pedido == 2 || estado_pedido == 3))){

                    SQL = SQL +"f_inicio_contrato = ?,f_fin_contrato=?,";
                }

                SQL = SQL +"id_estado_pedido = ? WHERE id_pedido = ?";
                System.out.println("EL SQL DEL UPDATE ES:"+SQL);
                PreparedStatement pstmAct = this.conexion.prepareStatement(SQL);
                if((f_aprobacion!=null)&&(((metodo_facturacion == 1)||(metodo_facturacion == 2 && (estado_pedido == 2 || estado_pedido == 3))))){
                    System.out.println("Dentro de if de f_aprobacion");


                    java.sql.Date f_aprobacionAux = new java.sql.Date(f_aprobacion.getTime());
                    pstmAct.setDate(1, f_aprobacionAux);

                    java.sql.Date f_inicio_contratoAux = new java.sql.Date(f_inicio_contrato.getTime());
                    pstmAct.setDate(2, f_inicio_contratoAux);
                    java.sql.Date f_fin_contratoAux = new java.sql.Date(f_fin_contrato.getTime());
                    pstmAct.setDate(3, f_fin_contratoAux);
                    pstmAct.setInt(4, estado_pedido);
                    pstmAct.setInt(5, pedido.getId_pedido());  // Pedido mÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â­o?

                }

                if((f_aprobacion==null)&&(((metodo_facturacion == 1)||(metodo_facturacion == 2 && (estado_pedido == 2 || estado_pedido == 3))))){
                    System.out.println("Dentro de if de f_aprobacion");

                    java.sql.Date f_inicio_contratoAux = new java.sql.Date(f_inicio_contrato.getTime());
                    pstmAct.setDate(1, f_inicio_contratoAux);
                    java.sql.Date f_fin_contratoAux = new java.sql.Date(f_fin_contrato.getTime());
                    pstmAct.setDate(2, f_fin_contratoAux);
                    pstmAct.setInt(3, estado_pedido);
                    pstmAct.setInt(4, pedido.getId_pedido());  // Pedido mÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â­o?

                }


                int ejecutadoPed =  pstmAct.executeUpdate();
                if(ejecutadoPed==0){    
                   throw new Exception("Error al actualizar Pedidos");
                }

                if(pedido.getDatos_cuentas()!=null){

                    for(int i = 0; i <pedido.getDatos_cuentas().length;i++){

                        TDatosRetorno result2 = actualizarCuenta(pedido.getDatos_cuentas()[i], true, false, true);

                        if(result2.getError()==-1){
                            throw new Exception(result2.getDescripcion_error());

                        }
                    }


                }



            this.conexion.commit();
            this.conexion.setAutoCommit(true);
            this.conexion.close();
            resultado.setError(0);
            resultado.setDescripcion_error("");
            return resultado;










        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();
                resultado.setError(-1);
                resultado.setDescripcion_error(e.getMessage());
                try {
                    this.conexion.rollback();
                    this.conexion.setAutoCommit(true);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
                return resultado;


    }





}
```

What is wrong?.Thanks

Comment: where is this running? inside some container like jboss, glassfish, tomcat? if so the configuration will be in different places.

Comment: it's running in a tomcat

Comment: and database and tomcat in different machines because tomcat is in my local and database in another machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database locks happen when there are `uncommitted transactions` pending. The database is waiting for an explicit `rollback` or `commit`.

The table you are waiting on **cluw.pedidos** appears to have such a transaction.

- check to see if there are other users holding an uncommitted transaction open
- check to see if your own query tool is holding an open transaction (check the preferences of your query tool for auto-commit or something like that)
- check the code of your application to see if a separate connection is still holding a transaction open

Depending on the number of rows being impacted by the database transaction, database engines may introduce `row-level-locking` or `table-level-locking` on any other changes until the `transaction` is completed.

Comment: ,I have added the code so you can see it better, I don't know why I have this lock.

Comment: The InnoDB Monitor output references an insert statement into **albaranes**, but I don't see such a statement in your code. It would appear that other transactions are holding each other up.

Comment: I have posted the code about albaranes. Could you see it and tell me if you see something wrong?. Thanks

Comment: do you see anything wrong in the code about albaranes?. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comment @majorbanzai, I have posted the new monitorization with the pieces of code about Albaranes.Could you help me in this way?. Thanks

Comment: I found the problem of this lock, and It was a call to connect again to the database and now I delete this and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Below is content from the innodb status that need to be closely watched.

`INSERT INTO albaranes    (id_cuenta_emisora,id_cuenta_receptora,id_pedido,id_formato_documento,descuento,nombre_report,destino_report) VALUES (    19 ,                           23 ,                         1 ,                                   2 ,                        0.0,                                null,null   )
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 8 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 228 n bits 256 index`PRIMARY`of table`cluw`.`pedidos`trx id  0 46087 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting`

All it means is that while inserting it is waiting for the lock on the primary key of table cluw.

You have foreign key constraint to table cluw and in a different transaction this row was created but not commited causing this transaction to wait.